# Android user presses a key

Tags: android

Is there a way to register a receiver for a app running in the background for when a user presses a key. Kind of like "ACTION_USER_PRESENT" but if any keys were pressed on the screen.

MORE DETAIL: My app is running as a service in the background. User opens the phone and presses keys, like they searching for something online on their driod. Can I capture those key presses in the background?

Comment: I seriously hope you can't do that. What you try to do is called "Keylogger" and a serious thread on each device (pc, laptop, phone, ...).

Comment: This kind of applications and services can really be a threat to the users privacy. I believe Mobile SDKs will not provide these APIs due to the nature of the problem it can create.

Comment: I am trying to create a keylogger for parents to lock down their child's phone. Imaging your 12 year old threatening to kill someone, or how they are struggling in schools. The security threat is not with the phone itself but in the safety of the child.

Comment: @WarrenFaith - Keyloggers are legitimate and are readily available for parents on PC's, Laptops and more.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but we all got grown up without something like that... And I don't grant my kids access do devices they can't control. But thats another topic. I am still interested if you find a way on a non rooted device.

Comment: None of us grew up with smartphones.  My first phone was as stupid as they come.  It was even attached to a wall!  How dumb is that?

Answer (score 0):

To detect whether a user is using the device you could also use the information whether the screen is on or off as an approximation (making the assumption that the screen timeout is set). [This blog entry](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/) shows how to capture the screen on and off events (I haven't done it myself though).

Answer (score 0):

In the Android HCI Extractor ( http://code.google.com/p/android-hci-extractor/ ) we traverse the GUI and install some event filters (by using listeners) in the app top view.

Maybe if you can reach a top level view from which listen the events you could listen to all the events for this view. Let's try ;-)

This tool is an open-source prototype you can find here: http://code.google.com/p/android-hci-extractor/

It is very easy to integrate and  use. In the tutorials you can see that only a few lines of code are needed: http://www.catedrasaes.org/trac/wiki/MIM

I hope it helps you!!